# HTML textarea in Elm where pressing tab adds \t and doesn't change focus

Tags: elm

I know how to listen for tab key presses in Elm. And I know how to stop the focus from being changed using `onWithOptions`:

```
textarea
    [ onWithOptions "keydown" (Options False True) <| Decode.map KeyDown keyCode ] []
```

I can then check, in my `update` function, if the `keyCode` pressed was a 9, representing a tab. The problem is now the default behavior of a `textarea` doesn't work. Anything I type doesn't appear in the `textarea`. Easy enough, I simply add whatever I type to the `model` and make the value of the `textarea` the model. Now I have issues with the cursor and, more importantly, clipboard pasting doesn't work...

How do I get tabs to work properly with `textarea`s in Elm? Normally, it would seem to make sense to only call `preventDefault()` if the tab key was pressed. How can I conditionally call `preventDefault()` in Elm?

Comment: Take a look at the work-around [@sentience has created](https://github.com/elm-lang/virtual-dom/issues/18#issuecomment-273403774) for this type of thing. It isn't ideal but it should get you what you need until we have conditional event propagation.

Comment: I got it to work with a similar but even easier mechanism than @sentience wrote in that issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elm does support conditional event propagation through a `Decoder` that either succeeds or fails. Simply `map` the message type you want to react to in your `update` function:

```
succeededIfTabKey : Int -> Decode.Decoder Int
succeededIfTabKey key =
    if key == 9 then
        Decode.succeed key
    else
        Decode.fail "non-tab"

tabPressed : Decode.Decoder Msg
tabPressed =
    Decode.andThen succeededIfTabKey keyCode
        |> Decode.map (always TabPressed)
```

And then use this as your attribute for your input element:

```
onWithOptions "keydown" { defaultOptions | preventDefault = True } tabPressed
```

This isn't ideal for all situations. If you want some `keydown` events to not `preventDefault()`, and other `keydown` events to `preventDefault()`, then you're out of luck.